# Is there a common noun form of the adjective "repetitive" that doesn't have a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, abstract-nouns

Is there a common noun form of the adjective 'repetitive' *that doesn't have a pejorative connotation* and that *denotes a state* rather than action?

**Edit**: I am not looking for the word 'repetition', as the suffix '-ion' conveys the meaning of "*action* or condition" (dictionary.com), which is not yet the level of abstraction I am thinking of.

I am tempted by the word **'repetitivity'** [and its suffix "-ity", which is "used to form abstract nouns expressing *state* or condition" (dictionary.com)]

But: Although the word 'repetitivity' exists (first detected in 1930 by [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=repetitivity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crepetitivity%3B%2Cc0)), it doesn't seem to be common within any discourse.
None of the dictionaries I consulted (Oxford Dictionaries, Cambridge Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, etc.) knows this word.
**But isn't it instantly intelligible?**

[Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/words/repetition-vs-repetitiveness/) knows the word "repetitiveness" but quite clearly states that the word has mostly a negative connotation (hence misunderstandings are around the corner!):

> - "**Repetitiveness** is the noun form of the adjective repetitive, which is used to describe something or someone as having the attribute of repetition. *This term is usually negative*, as in something repeats without need or becomes very tiresome in its repetition." [my italics]

Surprisingly, the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Repetitivity) knows the word "repetitivity" (the one I wanted to use) - but it assigns a negative connotation to this word too!

**Example sentence:** "English teachers often find it hard to convey to young learners such abstract ideas as generality and *repetitivity*, when they have to explain the main uses of the Simple Present tense."

**Important**: What I am looking for is a word for a concept *more abstract than the concept of "repetition"*.
Compare:

> exclusive - exclusion - *exclusivity*

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us a context in which you wish to deploy the word, and it may be worth adding the 'single-word-request tag (and reading the info on that tag).

Comment: @Spagirl Thank you for the info. I added a sentence. Obviously, this sentence could be reformulated in many different and easier ways! It's just an example sentence I put in order to meet the criteria of single word requests.

Comment: 'More general' in what way? The *excusivity* example is too sparse to act as an explanation.

Comment: Say a party was _exclusive_ in that it excludes a certain group of people: right-handed -smartphone users are excluded from this party! A day later, the news would title 'Scandalous _exclusion_ of right-handed phone users causes an uproar!' And scientists would appear on TV in live debates, discussing the degree of _exclusivity_ of such parties.  - More general in this way!

Comment: You can't just use the word *repeat*? A repeat is neutral. Many times, a repeat shows emphasis.

Comment: Did you do a thesaurus search for repetition?

Comment: @Mitch Yes I did, but I didn't find something that matches. See my Edit above. Also: Christian Geiselmann's iterativity comes closest so far.  I wish there was more discussion on my questions and findings. Maybe I need to ask philosophers that specialize in ontology. They'd sure come up with new words for conceptual categories.

Comment: @AshwinSchumann Look at an original Roget's (online). The section headings are great labels for abstract concepts above the usual abstract words. (which is to say a philosopher may well have a good word for you but a better search strategy is to look through the words and see if any match and go from link to link finding closer and closer words).

Comment: Also, dictionaries don't have all legally created and good sounding words.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an excellent research tool! @Mitch

Comment: Please read [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like [***recursiveness***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recursiveness) or [***recursivity***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recursivity), both of which are nouns meaning (Oxford Dictionaries):<sup>1</sup>

> The property of being [recursive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recursive)

which is an adjective that is a close synonym of *repetitive*. Again from Oxford Dictionaries:

> Characterized by recurrence or repetition.

Similar to your own "progression" of words, we thus have

> recur (verb) —> recurrence (fairly concrete noun) —> recursive (adjective) —> recursiveness/recursivity (more abstract noun)

I personally prefer *recursiveness* as slightly easier to say. (Your own suggestion of repetitivity I find particularly difficult to say, though it would otherwise work.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, the basic definition of both words is word-for-word identical, omitting only the cross-reference to one another.

Comment: 'Recursiveness' is great!

Comment: In computing science, recursive and iterative have very different meanings. Does recursive get a lot of use outside this technical setting?  Just curious.

Comment: @GlobalCharm I don't think it gets that much use, which makes it something of a blank slate for more specialist use. Philosophy/mathematics and linguistics also have specialized uses of the word, which each have slight variations from one another or the CS use; I think that works partially because the term doesn't have a really strongly defined lay meaning. I personally tend to use it when talking to about the research process, along with analogies like fractals and "rinse and repeat".

Answer (score 1):

What about plain and simply

> iterative

This is used quite commonly e.g. in computer programming routines where certain tasks have to be done repeatedly [!] but without this being negative; quite to the opposite, it is crucial that these steps are done a number of times running.

But of course the word is not a new one from the age of computers. Here is what Etymonline has for it:

> Iterative: "involving repetition," late 15c., from French iteratif (c. 1400), from Late Latin iterativus, from iterat-, past participle stem of Latin iterare "do again, repeat" (see iteration). As a noun, "an iterative word," by 1839. Related: Iteratively.

Comment: "Iterative" is an adjective, but I am looking for a noun. And that word should be more general than its nominal form "iteration". (It's basically the same question again.) I added a comparison in my last edit: exclusive - exclusion - exclusivity

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, you said you need a noun. *Iterativity* would not help, either?

Comment: I guess it's as intelligible as my "repetitivity" and yet not to be found in a dictionary, despite not being really discourse-specific, but simply a bit more abstract. I guess so far "iterativity" comes closest to what I was looking for.

Comment: Upon comparing 'repeat' (n.) and 'iterativity', I prefer the word by @Christian Geiselmann. It comes closest to what I meant. But what about 'repetitivity'?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you include "iterativity" into your answer so I can upvote the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be "a cognate of the adjective *repetitive*," and if it also has no "pejorative connotation," then the noun you are looking for is, I think, [**routine**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/routine):

> **1** A sequence of actions regularly followed.

---

For non-human actions, you can use either

[**sequence**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sequence) (as in "a sequence of sounds")

> **2** A set of related events, movements, or items that follow each other
>   in a particular order.

or you can use, even in very abstract contexts, the term [**string**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/string):

> **2.1** A sequence of similar items or events.

---

As to the noun corresponding to the adjective *iterative*, this is

[**iteration**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/iteration)

> **1** The repetition of a process or utterance.

Comment: I am looking for a word that equally applies to non-human actions or events. If I understand the word "routine" well, it stands for a sequence of actions performed by a human.
But what about a repetitive sound, a repetitive movement. Which word applies to that kind of concept of the repetitive?

Comment: Thanks for editing. I am still looking for a word that would allow to speak about the "-----ity" of your  'sequence of sounds' . Something like  'sequentiality', although so far I prefer iterativity. But still no one has told me their opinion on 'repetitivity'.? Have you ever come across that word?

Answer (score 0):

How about **persistence** or **perseverance**?  These are more general concepts than *repetition*, in the sense that a persistent individual can continue in their in their progress towards a goal either by repetition or variation, i.e. trying something new.  For example:

He wanted to see her badly.  He knocked, and knocked again. He pushed on the doorbell multiple times but to no avail. His shame made him persistent.  He would persevere until his words of apology and contrition could be honestly placed before her.  And the night was dark and stormy, which just made it all the worse...  (The raindrops struck persistently at his cloak...)

Answer (score 0):

One can say that something happens with **regularity**, with **uniformity**, like **clockwork**, in **rhythm**, or in **order**.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some form of cycle, or cyclical behavior.

From MW:

**[cycle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cycle)**

> 2 a :  a course or series of events or operations that recur regularly and usually lead back to the starting point

Answer (score 0):

Consistent "denotes a state", per your request.